# unresolved reference kotlin variable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter

I'm new to kotlin. I'm using the following code in my Adapter:

```
class TravelListAdapter(private var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TravelListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var onClickListener: TravelListAdapterListener
    lateinit var holderView: View

    interface TravelListAdapterListener {
        fun onClickListener(v: View, position: Int)
    }


     class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private lateinit var txtLabel: TextView

        fun MyViewHolder(view: View) {

            holderView = view // holderView shows error

            // in line below, holderView and onClickListener shows error
            holderView.setOnClickListener(
                View.OnClickListener { v -> onClickListener.onClickListener(v, adapterPosition) }
            )
        }

    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

The variables `onClickListener` and `holderView` have been declared in the Adapter class, but give this error when I access them in another class ( which is defined inside the Adapter class ):

> Unresolved reference: variable_name

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ??

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, you can directly access the member of outer class from the nested class.

In order to access the outer class members, you need to make your class as **inner** class as given in below snippt.

```
class OuterClass{

    var name="john"

    inner class InnerClass{

       //....
    }

}
```

So, here you need to define you **MyViewHolder** class **inner class MyViewHolder**

You can also check the same on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46730214/4083237

Answer (score 1):

Nested classed don't have access to *outer class members*.

Make your `MyViewHolder` an `inner` class.

Read more here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html